# Recover control buttons in xfce running backbox

Tags: xfce

Recently i was running XFCE desktop environment in Back box 4.6 based on Ubuntu 16.04, But later the window control buttons on the title bar of all applications disappeared after i ran a software update,I need to restore them.

Comment: Add a little more information, logs, what you "might" have done to cause this problem. Retrace your steps and think.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in a terminal `xfce4-settings-manager` and look around for the control buttons settings. You can also use this manager to change appearance settings, mouse settings etc..